# FIrestore data models and security rules of secret word function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I use Firebase and Firestore for my web app.
I would like to implement a secret word function.
If you know a secret word, you input a secret word and you can get a discount code.
How can I set up data models and security rules for this function in Firestore?

Example data:

- Question: 'What fruit do you like?'
- Secret Word: 'Orange'
- Discount Code: ORANGE50OFF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Security Rules stand between your **data** and **malicious users**. You can write simple or complex rules that protect your app's data to the level of granularity that your specific app requires, Firebase security rule protects your data against unauthorized access (your rule), You can implement secret code function using **nodejs or HTTP cloud function** by sending *HTTP request of secret code* and *get a discount* code by from server either reading from the cache at server-side or read from firebase database.

[image: DEMO]